# 2 sources one speaker - for old rotary phone

Tags: raspberry-pi, mobile, sparkfun

I have built a "mobile" phone using an old GPO 746, a Raspberry Pi and an old Nokia 6301, amazingly I have managed to get the audio to/from the phone's 2.5mm jack plug to through the GPO handset, audio in both directions is not great, but quite authentic!

To finish it off I would like to play a dial tone through the phone's earpiece when the handset is lifted off the hook. As the Nokia can't do this I thought that I would use the Raspberry Pi audio output through the earpiece.

My question is what is the best way to do this? i.e. connect 2 audio sources to one speaker. I haven't tried anything yet but doubt I can simply connect the 2 outputs to the same speaker without some sort of mixer/splitter which needs to be controlled by the start of the dial sequence.

Sequence is something like: Phone off hook -> play dial tone -> start to dial -> stop dial tone -> switch to audio from Nokia when call connected.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A mobile rotary phone is quite a gag.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't need to actually mix both audio sources together, just switch between them. Therefore you can get by with a dual SPDT analog switch, like the [TS5A23159](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts5a23159.pdf).

[image]

I chose a dual SPDT switch so you wouldn't have to deal with any issues tying the grounds of the two sources together.

The device is available in a DIP from [Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TS5A23159DGSR/296-18598-1-ND/862570) for under a dollar.

Note: the supply voltage can range from 1.65v to 5.5v, which makes it ideal to work with 3.3v devices such as the Raspberry Pi.  However the lines being switched cannot be greater than the supply voltage + 0.5v, or more negative than -0.5v.  If your audio lines exceed these limits, then consider my relay suggestion below.

========================================================

Another option would be to use a reed relay, such as the [HE700](http://www.hamlin.com/specsheets/HE700.pdf); you would need two of these since they are only SPDT.

[image]

They are available from [Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/HE721C0500/HE112-ND/133219) for $3.87.  I have used several of these myself and they work well.

The downsize here is that since the relay requires 5v, and the Raspberry Pi can only output 3.3v (and its pins are not 5v tolerant), you will need a transistor circuit, either a BJT or MOSFET to drive the relay.  There are plenty of answers here about driving relays from a microcontroller so I won't repeat that here.

Comment: If the "speaker" impedance is 32 or 8 ohms, that switch on-resistance (12 ohms in each leg) is quite significant; those switches tend to be used for line level. Discrete FETs with sub-ohm on-resistance - or a relay as you say - may be better (though the relay current may be more than you want in a mobile)

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks for pointing that out.  I was trying to keep with a DIP package, to make it easier to work with, but looked again and found a device in an MSOP package with an on resistance of 1 ohm.  Re the relay, if the relay is only on to present dial tone, then the current draw would be minimal.